# C code - Store int and char into 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, char, int, 2d

Im very new to programming, mind if you can teach me where is wrong or anything that i can add to my code. Can i add together of int and char value on the same array? or i need to use other method?

```
int main()
    {
        int i, j=1;
        int row, col;
        char x = 'x';
        char matrix[5][8]={
                          {x,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,x,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,x,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,x,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,x,0,0,0}
                          };   

        for(row=0;row<5;row++)
        {
            p(" A%i",j++);
            for(col=0;col<8;col++)
            {
                p(" %7i",matrix[row][col]);
            }

            p("\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This is the output

```
 A1     120       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 A2       0     120       0       0       0       0       0       0
 A3       0       0     120       0       0       0       0       0
 A4       0       0       0     120       0       0       0       0
 A5       0       0       0       0     120       0       0       0
```

The output is 120 instead of 'x' value. 
Help me please.
I want the output look like this

```
 A1       x       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 A2       0       x       0       0       0       0       0       0
 A3       0       0       x       0       0       0       0       0
 A4       0       0       0       x       0       0       0       0
 A5       0       0       0       0       x       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement looks incorrect. I think you're using the wrong specifier - i instead of c.

```
p(" %7c",matrix[row][col]);
```

I am assuming `p` == `printf` in one way or another. When I change that formatter, I get:

```
 A1       x                                                 
 A2              x                                          
 A3                     x                                   
 A4                            x                            
 A5                                   x
```

Comment: but @negacao, i need to print the integer value as well for calculation

Comment: so you want both the integer and the character? `p(" %7c %7i", matrix[row][col], matrix[row][col]);` ?

Comment: the output is messed up it showing both x and 120. You can refer my question, the output that i want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use %c to print a character. %i is goint to show it's numerical representation.

```
p("%7c", matrix[row][col]);
```

Comment: but  i need to print the integer value as well for calculation

Comment: I don't think I get exactly what you are trying to do. But you can always print as many variables as you like in any representation in printf. Like in `printf("Printing as character: %c   Printing as integer: %i", matrix[row][col], matrix[row][col]);`.   Just separate them by commas

Comment: the output is messed up   it showing both x and 120. You can refer my question, the output that i want.